# How to make own pattern validation

Tags: php, validation

I wanted to make my own pattern validation for my online shop so if they input wrong card pattern they will get a error and also to avoid XSS attack

Here is the pattern I used, using `GET` Method

4242424242424242|12|2022|000

CC NUM | Month| Year | CVV

I also have a code that will check if the CC NUM is valid

```
function validatecard($ccNumber)
 {
    global $type;

    $cardtype = array(
        "visa"       => "/^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/",
        "mastercard" => "/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/",
        "amex"       => "/^3[47][0-9]{13}$/",
        "discover"   => "/^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$/",
    );

    if (preg_match($cardtype['visa'],$ccNumber))
    {
    $type= "visa";
        return 'visa';

    }
    else if (preg_match($cardtype['mastercard'],$ccNumber))
    {
    $type= "mastercard";
        return 'mastercard';
    }
    else if (preg_match($cardtype['amex'],$ccNumber))
    {
    $type= "amex";
        return 'amex';

    }
    else if (preg_match($cardtype['discover'],$ccNumber))
    {
    $type= "discover";
        return 'discover';
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    } 
 }

validatecard($ccNumber);
```

But the problem here is that it only check the CC Num and I wanted to make a own pattern validation which I included at the top

Comment: Seems like your trying to "roll your own" credit card validation. Can I ask why?

Comment: There are many [php solutions](https://github.com/inacho/php-credit-card-validator) to accomplish this. You also may want to consider validating CCs on the client side.

Comment: Er... If you can effectively conduct a XSS attack by typing an invalid credit card number then the problem is somewhere else. BTW, why is your function returning the result *and* updating a global variable?